# Laravel-mix compile error: bundling javascript with typescript components library: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: typescript, webpack-4, laravel-mix, react-component

I'm starting a project with latest Laravel (6.5) and want to use react (16.9) in parts of the frontend. It worked fine with the first tests, but now I want to try a components library. I installed material-kit-react with npm:

```
npm i material-kit-react
```

In my .js file I import the component:

```
import CustomInput from "material-kit-react/src/components/CustomInput/CustomInput";
```

I tried to import it from "material-kit-react" but it was complaining about path, so I use to full path. Probably I'm missing a step here, cause I'm fairly new to npm/node_modules/webpack etc... and I know I'm missing some understanding of the whole situation.

And then in the component I return it:

```
    return (
        <div>
            <CustomInput
                labelText="With floating label"
                id="float"
                formControlProps={{
                    fullWidth: true
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
```

But I get this error during compilation (line 57 is the one with FormControl tag):

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/material-kit-react/src/components/CustomInput/CustomInput.js 57:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (57:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   }
|   return (
>     <FormControl {...formControlProps} className={formControlClasses}>
|       {labelText !== undefined ? (
|         <InputLabel
 @ ./resources/js/components/usuario/Registro.js 13:0-84 67:62-73
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
```

Following declarations, I've seen that it uses typescript, so I found out that probably I need ts-loader to bundle everything together, but after many hours I could not find a solution. I installed ts-loader (and typescript) via npm, added this to webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .webpackConfig({
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          loader: "ts-loader"
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx", ".vue", ".ts", ".tsx"]
    }
  });
```

Created a tsconfig.json file, tried with a .babelrc file cause I read that it might be because of that ("@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0" is installed as dev-dependency), but nothing...

So I would appreciate some light here, cause I guess that many libraries will use typescript! I searched options for laravel-mix, where I found this .webpackConfig, but nothing. Maybe I need to compile the library first to make it work with laravel?

Am I doing everything wrong from the beginning?

Many thanks in advance for your time!
Best regards,
Xavi

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

```
mix.webpackConfig({
resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx"]
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts|\.tsx$/,
            loader: "babel-loader!awesome-typescript-loader"
        }
    ]
}
});
```